# Command-line parsing: How to parse a string as an argument

Tags: c, parsing, cmd, switch-statement, arguments

I am attempting to parse a command line argument, which in turn will execute an associated `case` within a `switch` statement. When I parse an integer argument (as seen in the code below), the associated `case` executes correctly. When I attempt to parse a string such as "CPU", I do not get the correct output.

Functioning code (parsing an **integer** e.g. an argument of `4` gives athe correct output of `hello`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char execution_mode = atoi (argv[1]);

    switch (execution_mode)
    { 
    case (4) : 
        printf("Hello");
        getchar();
        break;
    case (8) :
        printf("Goodbye");
        getchar();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error! execution mode is not correct");
        getchar();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My attempt at parsing a **string** e.g. the argument`CPU`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    typedef enum MODE { CPU, OPENMP } MODE;
    MODE execution_mode = (char)argv[1];

    switch (execution_mode)
    { 
    case (CPU) : 
        printf("Hello");
        getchar();
        break;
    case (OPENMP) :
        printf("Goodbye");
        getchar();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error! execution mode is not correct");
        getchar();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the users who have answered this question, I have found a working solution by using `strcmp` as seen below. I have also added some error checking to ensure enough arguments have been enterred on the command-line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Ensure there are enough arguments 
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error: not enough arguments");
        exit(1);
    }

    typedef enum MODE { CPU, OPENMP, CUDA, ALL } MODE;
    MODE execution_mode = (MODE)argv[1];

    //Compare string with command-line arguments 
    if (strcmp("CPU", execution_mode) == 0)
    {
        //selects CPU case
        execution_mode = CPU; 
    }
    else if (strcmp("OPENMP", execution_mode) == 0)
    {
        //selects OPENMP case 
        execution_mode = OPENMP; 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("invalid arg");
    }

    //Switch statement 
    switch (execution_mode)
    { 
    case (CPU) : 
        printf("CPU MODE SELECTED");
        getchar();
        break;
    case (OPENMP) :
        printf("OPENMP MODE SELECTED");
        getchar();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error: execution mode is not correct");
        getchar();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a string to an enumerate like this. What you're doing is just converting the pointer to the string to `char`. Which fails.

One alternative (besides comparing first argument with `strcmp`) to avoid this would be to give a character value to your enumerates:

```
typedef enum { CPU='C', OPENMP='O' } MODE;
```

and now you can pick the first letter of the first argument and convert it:

```
MODE execution_mode = (MODE)argv[1][0];
```

The letters must be of course all different. And check `argc>1` to see if `argv[1]` is valid, of course

If you want full string match, you have no other choice than using `strcmp`:

```
const char *execution_mode = argv[1];

if (strcmp(execution_mode,"CPU")==0)
{ 
  // do something
}
else if (strcmp(execution_mode,"OPENMP")==0)
{
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: I think the strcmp method could work for me- I was thinking of doing an `if` statement like this: `if (strcmp("CPU", argv[1])) {.....}`  but I am not sure how to call the case from inside the curly brackets like that. Do you know how I could do this?